# relationship between $L^d$ convergence and a.s. convergence

Tags: probability-theory

I cannot find a valid counterexample that show that $L^d$ convergence doesn't necessarily imply a.s. convergence.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: $\chi_{[0,1]}, \chi_{[0,1/2]}, \chi_{[1/2,1]}, \chi_{[0,1/3]}, \chi_{[1/3,2/3]}, \chi_{[2/3,1]}, \dots$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X=[0,1]$ and lebesgue measure $m$. Take $$f_1=\chi_{[0,1]},$$ $$f_2=\chi_{[0,1/2]},\ \ \ f_3=\chi_{[1/2,1]},$$ $$f_4=\chi_{[0,1/4]},\ \ \ \ f_5=\chi_{[1/4,1/2]}, \ \ \ \ f_6=\chi_{[1/2,3/4]},\ \ \ f_7=\chi_{[3/4,1]} ...$$ etc, we see that $$\|f_n-0\|_{L^1(X)}=\int_X|f_n-0|dm \sim 1/2^{kn}. $$ Then $(f_n)$ tends to $0$ in $L^1(X)$ but, $f_n(x)=1$ for infinitely many values of $n$.